# How to let table cells automatically take up 100% width of table with table-layout: fixed?

Tags: css, layout, css-tables

I have the following requirements for table behavior on my website:

- cells will never get any explicit width, I will leave cell sizing to the browser based on content
- The table as a whole should never take up more than 100% width
- In some edge cases, even with an enforced max-width and the table wrapping, the total width may still exceed 100% (for example on mobile). In that case, I want the table be of 100% width, with horizontal scrolling.

To accomplish the above, checkout this [JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/likegavaje).

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Column one</th>
    <th>Column two</th>
    <th>Column three</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1.3</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    display: block;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    max-width:100%;
    background-color: #697A09 !important;
}

th, td {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:white;
    width:auto;
}
```

The thinking behind this setup: max-width on tables only works when the table is set to display:block. Horizontal scrolling for edge cases (small viewports) is accomplished using overflow-x in combination with table-layout:fixed.

This satisfies my requirements, but there is one unexpected issue: using display:block will make the table itself use 100% of width. However, the cells don't seem to follow that 100%, combined they take up far less than 100% of the table's width, as I tried to highlight in the example using different background colors.

What I basically want is to have the table always take up exactly 100% of whatever parent element it is in, and to have cells distributed across that 100%, without explicitly setting their width.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

the code might help as follows:

```
table {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    max-width:100%;
    background-color: #697A09 !important;
    width: 100%;
}

    th, td {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:white;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to change the behavior. Here is a version with your suggestions added: http://jsbin.com/bepuxemoda/1

Comment: it was not with that code piece there: with that code piece it is here: http://jsbin.com/gulozu/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks, but by removing display:block from the table, max-width no longer works, hence requirement #3 is not satisfied.